# Should you capitalize the word young before a name?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, capitalization, titles

So, let's say that there's someone named Zeth. 
Now, an elderly he know call him with the word young before his name:
Should it be "young Zeth" or "Young Zeth"? 
Truthfully, I just watched a movie or sort capitalized the word young before the name as it is quite make sense if I compare it with something like Elder *something* or title + name.
But "young" isn't a title, right?

Comment: No, young is not a title and should not be capitalised.

Comment: @Peter The only exception to that would be if there was another person called Zeth in the community, possibly young Zeth's father, who was already known as "Old Zeth". In that case the younger Zeth might be called "Young Zeth" whenever he was referred to so it became a nickname. There have been cases where people have had nicknames like that their whole lives through. If that happened then Zeth would be "Young Zeth" long after  "Old Zeth" died and after "Young Zeth" had children of his own. It's rare but it does happen.

Comment: @BoldBen, another exception would be if "Young" was used as a first name. That would be very unusual for people of English-speaking background, but possibly in somebody of non-English-speaking background.

Comment: @Peter That's true, but I was thinking of designations other than official names.